# How to show uploading process-bar in php?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, progress-bar

hello am trying to learn ftp file transfer in php. i have done all upload part. but i want to show uploading process-bar during the file transfer.

```
if file size 5MB
then a process-bar display uploading process as

523KB...uploaded...4min remaining
1.2MB...uploaded...3.5min remaining
2.5MB...uploaded...2.3min remaining
3.9MB...uploaded...1.4min remaining
4.4MB...uploaded...30sec remaining
Done...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need javascript for this.  Check here https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Wouldn't this only show a progress bar without any indication of the remaining time at all? The demo with the fileupload on that page also uses some sort of magical php script to retrieve the file upload state ;)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an easy task. As the server only calls the script when the upload is finished 100%.

You will need to use a flash-uploader or some special apache mods to get that information about an ongoing post request.

Flash-Uploader:
http://www.solmetra.com/en/disp.php/en_products/flash_uploader/uploader_intro

Or search for `libapache2-mod-upload-progress` and install that mod on your server.

Comment: its to complicated, can u suggest me to display a msg during a php script run?
like 'File  Uploading'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class available http://pear.php.net/reference/HTML_Progress-0.6.2/HTML_Progress/HTML_Progress_Bar_Horizontal.html
!caution: You should have a browser that accept DHTML feature.

Answer (score 1):

See this progress bar http://progphp.com/progress.php. It is created by Rasmus himself (creator of PHP). The source code can be seen at http://progphp.com/progress.phps. This example uses the APC module.

To show upload progress, you will need something like the [APC module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or the [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) PECL extension. The PECL extension seems to be preferred by some people.

Comment: I don't get this, how would the variable get into the APC store to get fetched in the first place?